# Can not resolve reference System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

Tags: xamarin.ios

my code error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can not resolve reference: /Users/mina/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CrewBriefingForms.iOS/b180de0d6d3aa6f1a31d57e58edee688/bin/iPhone/Debug/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
```

any one can guide me how to fix this issue

my tries to fix the issue
Navigate to directory to check if file exists or not and I figure its there

Answer (score 1):

`System.EnterpriseServices.dll` is not supported in Xamarin.iOS. You can refer to the [Supported Assemblies](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/) table from Xamarin documentation.

`System.EnterpriseServices.dll` is the dependency of some other dll, such as `System.Web`. You may find it and remove it from your Xamarin.iOS project to resolve the error.

References:

[Can not resolve reference: System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87745/can-not-resolve-reference-system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll)

[PSA - Don't use System.Web](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67362/psa-dont-use-system-web)